# Can I install ElementaryOS from a CD?

Tags: system-installation

I have the ISO downloaded from the ElementaryOS web site, in the install support only show how install from a USB Drive but I want know if can I burn the ISO in a CD and install from the CD?

I hope your response

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS Loki doesn't fit in a CD. You must use a DVD instead. Use any DVD record program to burn the iso in your DVD. Change boot priority in your Bios (some bios can select boot priority by F12 key) see your BIOS manual for instructions. Boot in live mode to see that everything works in your computer and once you have checked that your hardware runs well: install and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of CD burning software and burn the CD, and try to boot

the only difference I see is that you will need to set the CD as a boot option prior to HDD

Everything else should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Burn the .iso file into a cd using softwares like poweriso
**Remember to make it bootable**
Get into bios settings during startup 
**Make the priority into optical drive and save changes**
Else you are done

Here's a reference-style link to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ-6iYCDFrA&t=303s